# Windows Mobile - 2 Way Call Recording (C#)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to implement 2 way (caller and receiver) call recording on Windows Mobile. I have gone through many forums and articles saying that it's hardware limitation and is not possible on all phones. I have downloaded one application from http://www.resco.net/pocketpc/audiorecorder/ which is running perfect on my phone and has 2 way recording capability.

Is there any possibility of implementing same using .NET CF 2.0 (managed or unmanaged. although, managed is prefered.).

EDIT: I found [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446573.aspx), but not able to give the length of recording dynamically. I need to start when the call is received and stop when call is ended. So, length is not known at the time of recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Used [OpenNETCF.Media.WaveAudio.Recorder](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/d3b2ecbb-49b8-965a-89c2-d78c3781e7a1.htm) for 2 way call recording.

The only problem I faced was, Dynamic length for recording. I solved that by using [Recorder.DoneRecording](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/00d9ac38-a99a-2a6b-fbf9-91d9e161f059.htm) event. I created new .WAV file in each Recorder.DoneRecording and combining all .WAV files using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Concatenation_Wave_Files.aspx) at the end of recording (using Stop() method).

Comment: I think this is not for 2 way call recording. It records something but it's from the speaker also when you do RecordFor and someone call you, he won't be able to hear you because the microphone is locked by the OpenNETCF.Media.WaveAudio.Recorder. Can you give me a sample how to do 2 way call recording or maybe I missed something?