# Windows Mobile - Attach on call starting and recording a call

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I need to implement a small feature in my project for windows mobile 6.0+ platform. I want to attach to an event when a phone call is answered and to record the 2 way call. I saw this question:

[Windows Mobile - 2 Way Call Recording (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780173/windows-mobile-2-way-call-recording-c)

But it doesn't work in my case. When I start to record the microphone is blocked and the person on the other side can't hear my voice. I thought that maybe the problem is in the telephone(HTC Touch HD) but there are some programs that work, for example:

1. http://www.1800pocketpc.com/record-phone-calls-on-windows-mobile-htc-touch-hd/2925/
2. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=536472

I have two questions:

1. How to attach to a phone call?
2. How to record the phone call?

I appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Ivo

Comment: I've tried to do this once for an application on the 2003SE platform. It wasn't possible to do this in those days. I think it hasn't improved much since. The problem I was facing is I couldn't record the calling party's voice, so it was much like a voice recorder. Hope you find a way though...

Comment: I think for wm 6.0 it's possible i tried such app and it works

Comment: Have to tried those applications to verify they work on *your* device? As I understand it, those applications rely on HTC specific features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. According to the posts in the link below there is a hardware limitation preventing this ability in an application.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/65897b3b-da11-458b-b191-b9e4f6825843/

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. This is by design. It's illegal to record a call without informing the other party involved. Same is the case with iPhone. Though there are services where you call and they call other party and record the conversation, but that's server side.